# How can I pass additional parameters to predicate functions?

Tags: c#, sorting, parameters, predicate, parameter-passing

Can I pass additional parameters to a predicate function?

I need it in a sorting process actually.

```
public void Sort(
    Comparison<T> comparison
)
```

where I would like to use the `Comparison` predicate in this form:

```
public delegate int Comparison<T>(
    T x,
    T y,
    object extraParameter
)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you can do this:

```
public Comparison<T> MakeComparison<T>(object extraParameter)
{
    return
        delegate(T x, T y) 
        {
            // do comparison with x, y and extraParameter
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple capture the variables you need when you declare the predicate. Eg:

```
int i = 0, j = 10;

array.Sort(x => x > i && x < j ? 1 : -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party so i am answering this in case anyone comes across here by a google search (as i did).

You cannot pass more than parameter but you can do a trick to dodge that limitation:

Make it so the predicate requires a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) (or value tuple), that way you can pass more values by creating the tuple and passing it to the predicate. As far as i know the biggest tuple has a maximum of 3 parameters, but you can easily create your own tuples if you need to pass more parameters.

Edit1: The reason i suggested this instead of the above answers is that sometimes you are not declaring the predicate directly and instead using a method that returns bool as the predicate.

E.g:

```
public class Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4>
{
    public T1 Item1;
    public T2 Item2;
    public T3 Item3;
    public T4 Item4;
    
    public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4)
    {
       Item1 = item1;
       Item2 = item2;
       Item3 = item3;
       Item4 = item4;
    }
    
}

public struct ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3,T4>
{
    public T1 Item1;
    public T2 Item2;
    public T3 Item3;
    public T4 Item4;
    
    public ValueTuple(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4)
    {
       Item1 = item1;
       Item2 = item2;
       Item3 = item3;
       Item4 = item4;
    }
}
```